# How to change the value of a url parameter in ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is a better way to do this?

Ideally using a URI parsing class of some sort, rather than relying on my own regex

```rb
  url = "http://example.com"  //or "http://example.com?after=111"

  next_url = url.gsub(/after=\d+/,"666")
  if !next_url.eql?(url)
    if (new2.include?('?') == false)
      next_url = url + "?after=666"
    else
      next_url = url + "&after=666"
    end                                                                                                                                                                                        
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  puts next_url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the [Addressable](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.2.4/frames) gem when you are taking URLs apart or putting them together. It's very comprehensive, and has `query_values(options = {})` and `query_values=(new_query_values)` to extract all the query components into a hash, or to rebuild it from a hash. It will also handle decoding and encoding the parameters as needed, things that URI will not do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question, but you probably want something like this?

```
path, query = url.split('?')
query = (query||'').scan(/(.+)=(.+)/).map{|k, v| "#{k}=#{k == 'after' ? 666 : v}"}.join('&')
puts [path, query].join('?')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Ruby library called `URI` that handles parsing and building of URLs.